# Random first URL segment in Joomla

Tags: joomla, url-routing

I can't find a way to route this:

www.mysite.com/random_string

To a specific article in Joomla, and use "random_string" in my script

Solution should check if "random_string" is not the name of any article, category, etc

Joomla version is 2.5

Comment: You want a string of random characters for your url?

Comment: Not exactly. Users will come from different url's. Examples:

www.mysite.com/link1
www.mysite.com/link2
etc

When this first segment is not an existing article or anything in Joomla, I need to use it in my script, instead of throwing a 404.

Comment: Which they will get from where?

Comment: From other websites or from users recommendations. This segment will tell me who published my site and give credits to who deserves it. It'd be easy with URL params but that's not an option.

Comment: You're going to have multiple made up links going to the same page? You're no worried about Google?  I think you are going to save time and money by using an extension designed for this even if it is a commercial one.   What should happen on legitimate 404s by the way? And how will you tell them apart?

Comment: Yes. Why exactly should I be worried about Google? There would be no 404 page. Anything that is not a joomla article NOR anything else I'm expecting should render the home page. I'll check database for corresponding username or joomla article and act accordingly. Any framework can do that out of the box, I'm just not familiar with Joomla.

Comment: Because google will think that you are bait and switching people and take your homepage out of the A index if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with some .htaccess rewrite rules you can do it.

On your .htaccess try something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com/link_1$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php/menu_alias [L,R=301]
```

where menu_alias is the alias of a menu pointing to the article.

This is not enough if you need to count hits. If you need this then you may use .htaccess plus Joomla! Redirect Manager (Extensions->Redirect).

On the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com/link_1$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php/dummy_address [L,QSA,NC]
```

and then set a rule for dummy_address on the Redirect Manager which redirects to the true URL.

Last, you may try .htaccess plus a system plugin which fires on page render:

On the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com/link_1$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php/menu_alias?ref=link_1 [QSA,NC]
```

And write a content plugin to process the extra parameter.

Note that those redirections are internal, so they don't issue a 301 redirection, so they should be transparent to the client (I'm not 100% confident on this!).

Regards